# Pathfinder is making my NPC follow my oldest position only

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a maze/horror game. I used an online template in the Roblox library as my enemy. I used pathfinder as you will see in the code below. It's finding me like it's supposed to, except it only goes for my LAST position. As you can see in the image below, it completely skipped me, went to my LAST position, then started chasing me. I don't know why it only goes for my last position, and not my current position.

```
local PathFindingS = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local humanoid = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local rootPart = script.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
game.Workspace.Fruity.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 60       


--To calculate the path
while wait() do
    
    for i, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        local character = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(player.Name)
        local characterPos = character.PrimaryPart.Position
        local path = PathFindingS:CreatePath()
        path:ComputeAsync(rootPart.Position, characterPos)
        game.Workspace.Fruity.HumanoidRootPart:SetNetworkOwner(nil) 
        
        local waypoints = path:GetWaypoints()

        for i, waypoint in pairs(waypoints) do
            local part = Instance.new("Part")
            part.Shape = "Ball"
            part.Material = "Neon"
            part.Size = Vector3.new(0.6,0.6,0.6)
            part.Position = waypoint.Position + Vector3.new(0,2,0)
            part.Anchored = true
            part.CanCollide = false
            part.Parent = game.Workspace
            humanoid:MoveTo(waypoint.Position)
            humanoid.MoveToFinished:Wait()  
        end 
    end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NPC's pathfinding updates when you call `path:ComputeAsync(rootPart.Position, characterPos)`. The reason it is not updating more frequently is that you are blocking the start of the next loop with the last line : `humanoid.MoveToFinished:Wait()`

Your code is telling the NPC that it must walk to every single point between every single player, which could take minutes at a time, before ever calculating the path again.

The way to fix this is to make it so that the path can be recalculated quickly and asynchronously. To do this, try something like this :

```
local PathfindingService = game:GetService("PathfindingService")
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players") 
local humanoid = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local rootPart = script.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")


-- create a place where pathfinding orbs can be created and destroyed quickly
local shouldDebugPath = true
local OrbFolder = Instance.new("Folder", game.Workspace)
OrbFolder.Name = "Debug - Orbs"
local OrbTemplate = Instance.new("Part")
OrbTemplate.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
OrbTemplate.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
OrbTemplate.Size = Vector3.new(0.6,0.6,0.6)
OrbTemplate.Anchored = true
OrbTemplate.CanCollide = false
local function createWaypoint(position)
    local orb = OrbTemplate:Clone()
    orb.Position = position + Vector3.new(0,2,0)
    orb.Parent = OrbFolder
    
    return orb
end


-- set up some navigation variables and set up a chain
-- so that when the humanoid arrives at a waypoint,
-- it automatically selects the next point.
local currentOrbIndex = 0
local currentPath = {} -- store pathfinding waypoints here 
local function moveToNextWaypoint(previousPointReached) 
    currentOrbIndex += 1
    if currentOrbIndex > #currentPath then
        return
    end
    
    local nextWaypoint = currentPath[currentOrbIndex]
    humanoid:MoveTo(nextWaypoint.Position)
end
humanoid.MoveToFinished:Connect(moveToNextWaypoint)


-- calculate and continually update the path
local pauseLength = 1.0 --seconds (lower this number to speed up refresh rate)
while wait(pauseLength) do
    
    -- find the closest player's character model
    local targetCharacter = nil
    local closestDist = math.huge
    local playerList = PlayerService:GetPlayers()
    for i, player in pairs(playerList) do
        -- check that the player's character has spawned in
        local character = player.Character
        if not character then
            continue
        end
        
        -- do some quick maths and select which player is closest
        local p1 = character.PrimaryPart.Position
        local p2 = rootPart.Position
        local d = math.abs((p1 - p2).Magnitude)
        if d < closestDist then
            closestDist = d
            targetCharacter = character
        end
    end
    
    -- check that there are actually players in the server
    if targetCharacter == nil then
        continue
    end
        
    -- compute the path to the character
    local characterPos = targetCharacter.PrimaryPart.Position
    local path = PathfindingService:CreatePath()
    path:ComputeAsync(rootPart.Position, characterPos)
    local waypoints = path:GetWaypoints()
    
    -- debug : show the path to the player
    if shouldDebugPath then
        OrbFolder:ClearAllChildren()    
        for i, waypoint in pairs(waypoints) do
            local position = waypoint.Position
            createWaypoint(position)
        end
    end
    
    -- start the player walking towards the nearest player
    currentOrbIndex = 0
    currentPath = waypoints
    moveToNextWaypoint()
end
```

This solution recalculates the path to the nearest player every 1 second. That path is stored as a series of waypoints and it uses the [Humanoid.MoveToFinished signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/MoveToFinished) as the trigger to move to the next known waypoint. Whenever the path is recalculated, we simply start the process over.

With this system, the loop isn't blocked and the distance and path to the different players can be regularly recalculated. This allows the NPC to dynamically switch targets towards the closest player too.

Comment: thank you so much, Pathfinder makes much more sense now!!

Comment: for line 22, where it says "return part", I'm assuming you said to "return orb"? It's showing me an error that's saying, "Global error could not be found".

Comment: Ah yep, last second edit got me. You're right, it should be `return orb`